# ssl using flask and python3, works on Ubuntu but not Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, flask

I had the issue on Ubuntu (14.04) on AWS but resolved it by upgrading my Python to 3.4.3 (from 2.7). However, I still get the issue locally (Mac Yosemite, v10.10.5) even though Ive upgraded my python. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "payment_app.py", line 97, in <module>
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

My Python version (python3 --version) on my Mac is:

```
Python 3.4.4
```

Is there any differences between Mac:s version of Python and Ubuntu:s? If so, how to I handle this error?

Thanks in advance.

Peter

Comment: The python versions are the same, but the ssl libraries aren't and that's where the problem lies.  What version of OSX are you running?

Comment: How did you install Python 3?

Comment: The brute force (but foolproof) option is to simply download your server VM image and run it in a virtual machine locally. For instance, using something like VirtualBox. That way you know that there shouldn't be any differences between your server setup and your local development environments. Virtualbox even allows you to mount a shared drive between the host and guest. That way you can use the Mac OSX development tools you like, but still test in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Logan Im running on version 10.10.5 (14F27). How should I progress in a) finding the differences between the ssl libs and b) making sure I use the correct/same ssl lib?

Comment: @TravisMehlinger I used [https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/]. Why? Is there a difference between "mac:s version" and "ubuntu:s version" of Python?

Comment: @eestrade, thanks. Id prefer not to have to go to such lenghts but maybe as a last resort.

Comment: Can you run this:  import OpenSSL
 print(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLeay_version(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLEAY_VERSION))

Comment: @Logan. I guess I should do this on my Mac. I did this in the python3 shell. `import OpenSSL`yields "ImportError: No module named 'OpenSSL'". `sudo pip3 install OpenSSL`yields "No matching distribution found for OpenSSL"

Comment: That might be using whatever system Python OSX uses.  To be certain you're using the right python give it the full path and then -m pip install openssl

Comment: @Logan. I got it to work with `sudo pip3 install pyopenssl`. ` import OpenSSL print(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLeay_version(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLEAY_VERSION)) ` now yields "b'OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015'". Im afraid Im still getting the original error even though pyOpenSSL now seams to be installed. Any idea how to progress here?

Comment: import pyOpenSSL and use it's libraries for anything ssl related?

Comment: @Logan. As mentioned above, Im on OSX and as I understand it pyOpenSSL installs OpenSSL on mac so `import pyOpenSSL` just yields: "ImportError: No module named 'pyOpenSSL'". I installed this to be able to run your previously suggestion " import OpenSSL print(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLeay_version(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLEAY_VERSION))". This now works and prints "b'OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015'". Does this print tell you anything?